# Linux kernel keeps waking up HDD that was put to sleep via hdparm

Tags: linux, debian, hard-disk, sata, hdparm

*(My system is Debian 11 Bullseye + GNOME 3.38.6)*

I have a Seagate 2TB only for storage purpose, and as it's quite loud I put it to sleep unless I access the storage, using the command:

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda
```

When above is executed, the HDD goes to sleep, but after several minutes something wakes the HDD up and I cannot figure out what.

I checked the journal, and apparently every 10 minutes the following occurs right before the HDD wakes up again:

```
Jun 09 20:36:59 user0 kernel: ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jun 09 20:36:59 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 09 20:36:59 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 09 20:36:59 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Jun 09 20:37:02 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Jun 09 20:37:02 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Jun 09 20:37:02 user0 kernel: ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Jun 09 20:37:02 user0 kernel: ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

What's causing this/how can I prevent this?

UPDATE. The above messages only appear if the HDD was put to sleep. Otherwise they don't recur in the journal.

Comment: Is it mounted ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Well, I don't think so, because I tried to unmount it but it said it is not mounted.

Comment: The Linux kernel never accesses your disks unless instructed so by userspace. Your disk is either mounted or used by some applications one way or another. I have a spare HDD which normally sleeps and never gets woken up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ArtemS.Tashkinov Actually the sleep command used to work great (meaning the HDD won't wake up itself). But at some point in this month it strated waking up itself. I'm in Debian and I really didn't install anything other than very minimal coding stuff like python packages, so I believe it's unlikely that my userspace is causing it to wake up (OR the gnome env could?)... What I did though is updating my system, which hadn't done for a while, and in Windows (dual boot) I changed some parameters of the HDD (like APM level, etc) via Seagate SeaChest. Could that be a reason?

Comment: It's very unlikely that APM parameters could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that helps you know what's causing it, but not how to fix it.

You'll need a kernel compiled with `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE=y` (you can check this with command `$ zcat /proc/config.gz |grep BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE` but only if kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y`).

Now that you have that, you can use [`btrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/btrace)/[`blktrace`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace) (debian package is [blktrace](https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/blktrace)) as root, like:

```
$ sudo btrace /dev/sdc
```

or the equivalent: `sudo blktrace -d /dev/sdc -o - | blkparse -i -`

which will give you output like the following but only when accesses to /dev/sdc (use sda for yourself) happen:

```
  8,32   4        1     0.000000000 35200  Q FWS [sync]
  8,32   4        2     0.000005329 35200  G FWS [sync]
  8,32   4        3     0.000024868   166  D  FN [kworker/4:1H]
  8,32   0        1     0.005341892 35201  D   R 36 [sdparm]
  8,32   0        2     0.005360604    12  C   R [0]
  8,32   0        3     0.005483027 35201  D   N 0 [sdparm]
  8,32   2        1     0.008090821 13354  D   R 32 [(null)]
  8,32   2        2     0.008109065    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2        3     0.008274033 13354  D   R 64 [(null)]
  8,32   2        4     0.008290535    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2        5     0.008435087 13354  D   R 64 [(null)]
  8,32   2        6     0.008451221    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2        7     0.008649311 13354  D   R 8256 [(null)]
  8,32   2        8     0.008665588    24  C   R [65415]
  8,32   2        9     0.008839399 13354  D   R 8 [(null)]
  8,32   2       10     0.008856004    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2       11     0.008905781 13354  D   R 512 [(null)]
  8,32   2       12     0.008913061    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2       13     0.008957477 13354  D   R 512 [(null)]
  8,32   2       14     0.008963625    24  C   R [0]
  8,32   2       15     0.017343228 35206  Q  RA 35156656000 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       16     0.017344264 35206  G  RA 35156656000 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       17     0.017344513 35206  P   N [udevd]
  8,32   2       18     0.017344733 35206  U   N [udevd] 1
  8,32   2       19     0.017344993 35206  I  RA 35156656000 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       20     0.017346335 35206  D  RA 35156656000 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       21     0.017613109 35206  Q  RA 35156655864 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       22     0.017613575 35206  G  RA 35156655864 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       23     0.017613672 35206  P   N [udevd]
  8,32   2       24     0.017613775 35206  U   N [udevd] 1
  8,32   2       25     0.017613935 35206  I  RA 35156655864 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       26     0.017614656 35206  D  RA 35156655864 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       27     0.017728317 35206  Q  RA 35156656064 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       28     0.017728616 35206  G  RA 35156656064 + 8 [udevd]
  8,32   2       29     0.017728680 35206  P   N [udevd]
  8,32   2       30     0.017728750 35206  U   N [udevd] 1
```

You can see some process names that used /dev/sdc, such as sync, sdparm, udevd and kernel kworker.